# How can I duplicate each rows in sql query

Tags: sql-server, duplicates, record

I have been trying to find out a solution for this case.

Now I am currently trying to create and retrieve duplicate values in each row in a single table

```
date      date_year, date_month, date_day, weeday_nm, start_time,               end_time
2014-10-6  2014       10           6         Monday    2014-10-06 00:00:00.000,2014-10-06 23:59:59.000
2014-10-7  2014       10           7         Tuesday   2014-10-07 00:00:00.000,2014-10-07 23:59:59.000
```

In output, I would like to see a record

```
date      date_year, date_month, date_day, weeday_nm, start_time,               end_time
2014-10-6  2014       10           6         Monday    2014-10-06 00:00:00.000,2014-10-06 23:59:59.000
2014-10-6  2014       10           6         Monday    2014-10-06 00:00:00.000,2014-10-06 23:59:59.000
2014-10-7  2014       10           7         Tuesday   2014-10-07 00:00:00.000,2014-10-07 23:59:59.000
2014-10-7  2014       10           7         Tuesday  2014-10-07 00:00:00.000, 2014-10-07 23:59:59.000'
'
'
'
'
'
```

there are so many rows is there any way that I can complete this case?

Comment: So you have a table containing unique records and you would like duplicate each of those records and then return the set of duplicates?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are looking for but "union all" might help. select * from my table union all select * from mytable

Comment: yes, i have a table only listing dates in order and yet i would like to see  return values with a record containing duplicated value in each row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `CROSS JOIN` to a table with two rows in - easiest way if you are using SQL Server 2008 or later is to use a table valued constructor e.g.

```
SELECT  t.*
FROM    YourTable AS t
        CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1), (2)) AS cj (Number)
```

If you are using an earlier version use:

```
SELECT  t.*
FROM    YourTable AS t
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT Number = 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2) AS cj;
```

This way you can duplicate the records without having to read the table twice.

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer and also the explanation.  it works perfectly